# Translate "Soroban" as "abacus" or "Japanese abacus"?

Tags: word-choice

While "soroban" can be used as a word in English, I wouldn't use it in everyday conversation - I'm a Japanophile and I didn't know the word!

While googling the word, I came across Wikipedia's entry defining it. Before reading its entry on soroban, and its entry on abacus, I didn't realize that there were other kinds of abaci.

Would I use "abacus" or "Japanese abacus" for the soroban?

Answer (score 2):

While this has some touch of being opinion based, I suggest you take a worst-case approach:

- If you say *abakus*

  - people *will* understand "frame with moveable thingies used to calculate".
  - They *will not necessarily* understand "frame with moveable thingies, divided in two parts, one higher representing five and a lower representing 1-4 or 1-5", because different people might think of different layouts first.
- If you say *Japanese abakus*

  - people *will understand* "thing that helps to calculate something, likely with moveable thingies, either made in Japan or originating in Japan."
  - They *will not necessarily* understand "frame with moveable thingies, divided in two parts, one higher representing five and a lower representing 1-4 or 1-5, traditionally used in Japan."

So be prepared to add some explanation in any case. My gut feeling is that "Japanese abacus" is closer to "soroban", especially if including the part about it being *Japanese* is important for you.

And why not use ...*soroban, the japanese abacus*...